# How can I catch that View become visible

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I inflate Views on ScrollView.

And I need to get event, when on scrolling one of this Views (last, for example, or special type) becomes visible (in screen zone).

Answer (score 0):

If a view changes visibility, the onlayout method is called, you could try overwriting that method and check it's state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the view's [`onVisibilityChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onVisibilityChanged%28android.view.View,%20int%29). This is also called when one of the view's ancestors changes visibility.

Answer (score -1):

This I inflated my GridView and get what you want

```
public class MyGrideView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public MyGrideView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGrideView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGrideView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's example for "onInflate", but I find solution for "onScroll". For exampe, when we get top or end of MainMenu in our Android on scrolling, this border highliting by blue color. It is some event, so I need catch this event in my App.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question